# How can I get count of document in one to many relation with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have two schemas.

```
// tutorial
export const TutorialSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Tag"
        }
    ]
})

// tag
export const TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    companyId: Number
})


constructor(@InjectModel('Tutorial') private readonly _tutorialModel: Model<any>) { }
```

I want to get count of tags for each tutorial (in one query). How can I do that ?
I know how to get list of tutorial.

```
const result = await _tutorialModel.find()
```

Comment: If you really need only count, you can just check the array size. Something like _tutorialModel.tags.length;

If you want also to load the tags:

1. You can use $lookup, which is very inefficient (because this is not really SQL's joins equivalent)
2. You can pull tutorials, then pull all tags in a single query and map them manually

Comment: In short, if you need the values, read about populate API: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html just ensure you understand how it works. There are more efficient ways to do it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group` aggregation in the following way -

```js
_tutorialModel.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         title: 1,
         _id:1,
         numberOfTags: { $cond: { if: { $isArray: "$tags" }, then: { $size: "$tags" 
       }, else: "NA"} }
      }
   }
] )
```

For Size operator you need to ensure first that `tags` is always an array! If for any reason `tags` is not present then error will be thrown.

If you make sure `tags` will be always present and is an array then you can simplify to following -

```js
_tutorialModel.aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         title: 1,
         _id:1,
         numberOfTags: {$size: "$tags"}
      }
   }
] )
```

Take a look at -

Size aggregation operator -
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/